# All browsers crashing

Tags: browser, crash

I have 3 browsers installed on my computer: IE 8, FF 4, and Chrome.
Some weeks ago, all started crashing at random times.
I tried disabling add-ons, but that did not seem to help.

A few days ago I reinstalled Windows, but the crashes are still here. I thought the cause might be the antivirus (Windows Security Essentials), and installed Avast instead, but still the browsers crash.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Do you receive error messages when they crash, do they freeze first, or do they just simply disappear? After you reinstalled, did you reload any data back on the system from a backup source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Word now crashed too.
Thanks to its diagnostic tool, I now know that the cause is faulty RAM.